# ASP.NET Core Entity Model Automatically Maps to View Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core RTM (Full .NET Framework).

I ran into some unexpected behavior with a controller that accepts an entity model as a parameter and returns a view model.  In the controller I create a new instance of the view model and use the entity model to populate it.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create(ActiveDirectoryUser model)
{
    ApplicationUserView user;

    user = new ApplicationUserView
    {
        UserName = model.UserName,
        Email = model.Email.ToLower(),
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        Active = true
    };

    return View(user);
}
```

With the code above I noticed that the email address is not changed to lower case in the view even though in debug the ApplicationUserView object shows that the email is lowercase.

So I did a test where I used static values for the ApplicationUserView object.

```
user = new ApplicationUserView
{
    UserName = "Test",
    Email = "test@test.com",
    FirstName = "Test",
    LastName = "Test",
    Active = true
};
```

With the code above the view still shows the values that were passed in by the ActiveDirectoryUser model.

I don't understand how the values from the ActiveDirectoryUser model are making it to the view and why I can't override them.  I've tried to override them in the constructor as shown above and also tried setting them individually like `user.Email = "test@test.com"`.

How can I pass my ApplicationUserView model to the view without any data from the ActiveDirectoryUser model?

Comment: Your current code(the one on the top of the question) is setting the property values of your `ActiveDirectoryUser` object to your view model. If you do not want that, do not set the values. What exactly is the problem you are facing ? You do not want any values or you want email value in lowercase ? Sorry ! i am confused about your expected behavior

Comment: As stated, the original issue was that the email address was not being changed to lowercase.  I couldn't figure out why so I did the tests I mentioned and unexpectedly found that the values from the `ActiveDirectoryUser` model went to the view no matter what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ModelState.Clear();` before you send the model back. The page model is stored in ModelState which takes precedence over your current model.
Also i assume that `ApplicationUserView` is the model that your view is bound to..

Comment: That fixed my issue.  And yes, my view is bound to the `ApplicationUserView` model.  Thanks!